# When is a dataset too large for my machine's memory?

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, bigdata, dask

So the Dask tutorials state that:
"For too large datasets (larger than a single machine's memory), the scikit-learn estimators may not be able to cope"

Am I correct in saying: if I have 9.42 GB of "available physical memory" showing up on the System page, then a "too large dataset" for scikit would be anything in excess of 9.42 GB of data?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use anything in excess of 6~ gb of data, although an extremely wild and vague guess. The question in itself is quite vague and doesn't address a specific issue within the scope of this page

Comment: This is kind of syllogistic isn't it?

Comment: Try it, see how much memory pressure certain data loads cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in saying: if I have 9.42 GB of "available physical memory" showing up on the System page, then a "too large dataset" for scikit would be anything in excess of 9.42 GB of data?

Roughly yes, though the exact upper limit on the data size depends on various factors (such as which other objects are in the memory, how different algorithms handle copies or subsets of the data), etc. A rough rule of thumb for pandas dataframe is to use dataframes that are about 1/5 of the available RAM, and a similar ballpark estimate might be reasonable for scikit (with the caveat that much depends on the exact code/algo used).

Note that some scikit estimators can be fit on partial data, see [this page](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html).